# Laravel 8 + Inertia is not rendering variables

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I actually struggling with passing data into GET request page where I trying to pass data from database to Dashboard.vue component (Using Laravel 8 + Inertia.js stack)

But nothing happened, why?

Controller component:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
        return Inertia::render('Dashboard', [
            'percentages' => $percentages = DB::table('profits')->where('user_id', $request->user()->id)->sum('percentage'),
            'profits' => $profits = DB::table('profits')->where('user_id', $request->user()->id)->sum('total_profit'),
            ]);
}
```

Front-end:

```
    <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-5 text-center fund-profits">
                          {{profits}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 text-center nomad-separator">
                            |
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5 text-center fund-profits">
                          {{percentages}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
   </div>
    
        <script>
            import JetApplicationLogo from './../Jetstream/ApplicationLogo'
        
            export default {
                props: ['percentages', 'profits'],
                components: {
                    JetApplicationLogo,
                },      
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem yesterday.
I was rendering again in `routes/web.php` via inertia, and I believe there was a overwriting. Try without using inertia in your routes, worked for me.

> Route::get('/your_route', [YourController::class, 'index'])

Answer (score 0):

creator of Inertia.js here.

I don't see any issue with what you're doing here, assuming that the Vue component you're showing is in fact the `Dashboard.vue` page component.

What I'd recommend is using the [Vue devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) to inspect the props that being received, to make sure they are coming from the server properly.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the route middleware for inertial was not applied so i applied route middleware inertia and it started working again

[server side ineertiajs](https://inertiajs.com/server-side-setup)